# How to use WHERE condition to filter database table 'ID' vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, pdf

I wanted to filter database table using WHERE condition and save asper filter 'ID'

Database table:

| ID | Name | Class | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Todkar Sudhir S | 1st | 30-10-2022 |
| 1001 | Todkar Sudhir S | 1st | 31-10-2022 |
| 1002 | Sawant pooja B | 2nd | 30-10-2022 |
| 1002 | Sawant pooja B | 2nd | 31-10-2022 |

This is my code which I tried to get result but I'm not understanding how to use where condition and how to save in iTextsharp pdf on 'ID'

```
   Dim table As New PdfPTable(4)
        table.TotalWidth = 416.0F
        table.LockedWidth = False
        Dim widths As Single() = New Single() {1.0F, 2.0F, 3.0F, 4.0F}
        table.SetWidths(widths)
        table.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        table.SpacingBefore = 20.0F
        table.SpacingAfter = 30.0F
        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Table Batch"))
        cell.Colspan = 4
        cell.Border = 0
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1
        table.AddCell(cell)
        Dim connect As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-D32ONKB;Initial Catalog=Attendance;Integrated Security=True"
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connect)
            Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
            Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("D:\pdf\" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") & ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
            pdfDoc.Open()
            Dim query As String = "SELECT ID,Name,Class,Date FROM stuattrecordAMPM where ID=@ID"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            Try
                conn.Open()
                Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While rdr.Read()
                        table.AddCell(rdr(0).ToString())
                        table.AddCell(rdr(1).ToString())
                        table.AddCell(rdr(2).ToString())
                        table.AddCell(rdr(3).ToString())
                    End While
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            pdfDoc.Add(table)
            pdfDoc.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to add a [Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter) named `@ID` and set a value to it

Comment: If your issue is about querying a database then that's what your code should show. It's good to provide background explanation but the code should be the minimum required to demonstrate the issue. Writing data to the PDF is irrelevant because your issue is getting the data in the first place. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and make sure to abide by it in future. You should already be doing such minimal tests as part of your own debugging anyway.

Comment: @Jimi, Thank you for respond  cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int) can I use this parameter.

Comment: Well, yes, that's in the Docs I've linked. You can in-line the `.Value` (also in the Docs)

Comment: @Jimi, 'cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 50).value=' what value to give after = .

Comment: The `ID` value of the record you want to fetch (e.g., `1001`). Why did you add `50` there, that's an `int` Column -- The Docs are there for your convenience and there are thousands of questions here about this matter. Take a look around

Comment: @Jimi, Thanks for updating me. "cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).value=" without '=' Its coming error line what value I have to give after '='

Comment: Well, of course you need to specify that value (an `Integer` value, corresponding to the `ID` Column of the record you want to retrieve). You have records with the same `ID`, so you'll get two records per `ID` in each request

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to use Add Method of sqlCommand parameters

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection(connect)
       ...
            Dim query As String = "SELECT ID,Name,Class,Date FROM stuattrecordAMPM where ID=@ID"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
        cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = <ID e.x. 1001>
       ...
End Using
```

Visit this topic for more information:
[SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)